# Microsoft Word VBA Find how many occurrences of a word there are on a single designated page in a document with many pages

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working to develop code that is to be used as a part of a greater code set that will ultimately answer how many times a specific word appears on a single specified page within a Word document that could have many pages in it.

What the code is actually attempting to accomplish is to search for a phrase on only one page at a time, find that phrase, then copy the string immediately following where that phrase was found on that page and pasting string to a different word doc. If you anyone can come up with a better approach than what I have below I am open to changing things up, as this has been much more difficult of a task than what I thought it would be in the beginning.

```
Sub test()

'Find and Define Documents
Dim doc As Document
For Each doc In Documents
       If Left(doc.Name, 5) = "LEGAL" Then
       Dim MainDoc As Document
       Set MainDoc = doc
    End If
Next doc

For Each doc In Documents
    If doc.Name = "Document1" Then
       Dim OtherDoc As Document
       Set OtherDoc = doc
    End If
Next doc

'Start from top of main doc.
MainDoc.Activate
Selection.GoTo What:=(0)

'count # of pages in main doc. 
Dim iCount As Integer
iCount = 0

'Do for other procedures to be accomplished in the code
Do While iCount < ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")
iCount = iCount + 1
MainDoc.Activate
Dim Range_Doc As Range
Set Range_Doc = MainDoc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=iCount)
Set Range_Doc = Range_Doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")

'Find & Count the number of times the word Apple appears on specific page
    Dim AppleCount As Integer
    If AppleCount > 0 Then
        Dim OriginalCount As Integer
        OriginalCount = AppleCount
    End If

    AppleCount = 0

   Range_Doc.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Select
    'Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "Apple"
        .Format = False
        .Wrap = 0
        .Forward = False

      Do While .Execute
        AppleCount = AppleCount + 1
      Loop
    End With

    Dim NewCount As Integer
    NewCount = AppleCount - OriginalCount

    If NewCount < 0 Then
        NewCount = 0
    End If


    'Locate where in the doc the find term was found and extract what is coming after it
    Set Range_Doc = MainDoc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=iCount)
    Set Range_Doc = Range_Doc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")

    Dim objFind As Find
    Set objFind = Range_Doc.Find
    With Range_Doc.Find
       Counter = 0
       Do While .Execute(findText:="Apple", MatchWholeWord:=False, Forward:=True) = True And Counter < NewCount

       With Range_Doc
          Set objFind = Range_Doc.Find

          If objFind.Found Then
             Dim Range_Found As Range
             Set Range_Found = objFind.Parent

             Dim IntPos as Integer
             IntPos = Range_Found.End

             Dim AppleID
             Set AppleID = MainDoc.Range(Start:=IntPos, End:=IntPos + 33)

             OtherDoc.Content.InsertAfter ","
             OtherDoc.Content.InsertAfter AppleID

          End If

        End With
        Counter = Counter + 1
        Loop
    End With

Loop
End sub
```

Comment: Documents don't have pages. Only printed rendering of the same do. Change the font size or margins and pages will change. Documents have Sections, Paragraphs, Sentences and Words.

Comment: That's a serious over-simplification. The fact is, content in a Word document can be processed by page - as the OP's code clearly demonstrates

Comment: @Taylor_D It's not apparent from your code what the significance of looping through the pages might be - it doesn't appear to contribute to the output.

Comment: So what is happening is there are multiples of the same forms sent to us in the same document. On page 1 is one form page 2 is a new form page 3 and 4 are the same form cause there was more info that ran over on to the next page. And this goes on for about 80 more pages. So what I'm looking to do is loop through all pages and extract only the info I need from each form. I can do this as each form has a unique set of words right before the info I need to extract. So I am looping through each page, finding the terms I'm searching for then taking the terms that come immediately after and copying

Comment: Them and pasting them into a different document. The problem comes from some times those same terms can appear more than once and therefore I need to loop inside each page to pull each of the terms that follow my search term. Let me know if that makes more sense.

Comment: I must also associate which form produced which extracted terms. So first I extract the unique tracking id of each form, which appears at the beginning of each form, and then I need to extract each case id included in that particular form. So form 1 I need to extract the tracking Id and then the 2  case IDs associated to that tracking Id and then on form 2 I need to extract the tracking Id and the 4 case IDs and so forth. In order to find where the tracking id and case IDs are in the forms I am using the find function to locate their position

Comment: I did not include the code I use for extracting the tracking IDs cause that code works fine since it knows that the tracking Id can only appear once per page if at all. But since each page can contain more than 1 case Id, this is what is giving my code trouble

Comment: @Taylor_D One would expect, therefore, that each form would be separated from the one before/after by a Section break - and that there might even be multiple Sections per form. Is that so?

Comment: That probably is true but am not sure you could count the sections with in the form as one form might have 4 sections but the next might have 10 sections within that one form depending on how much info each has in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something based on:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim DocSrc As Document, DocTgt As Document, Rng As Range
Set DocSrc = ActiveDocument: Set DocTgt = Documents.Add
With DocSrc
  Set Rng = .Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=3)
  Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
  With Rng.Duplicate
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "Apple"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = True
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      If .InRange(Rng) = False Then Exit Do
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .End = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End -1
      DocTgt.Range.Characters.Last.Text = vbCr & .Text
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

where the content you're interested in is on page 3.

Comment: I am away from my computer at the moment but I will try this when I get back. Appreciate the help and will follow up in the morning. Thanks again

Comment: That sure did it much cleaner than my approach! Thank you very much. For those interested, I also did find another solution which was to just select the page before doing my With Selection.Find by using `       Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, iCount     |
       Selection.Bookmarks("\Page").Select`

Comment: Using Selections is inefficient and prone to producing screen flicker.

Comment: I agree. I implemented your solution. Much cleaner. Great work and thanks again friend.

Comment: Is there a way to write this part .End = .End + 33  if say I didn't know it would be a guaranteed 33 characters and just wanted to pull in everything to the end of the line or paragraph instead?

Comment: Had you said that's what you wanted from the outset, I'd have written the code differently. As it is, try: .End = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End -1.